# Arcgis online and Collector: Controling shared maps and data

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I am using ArcGIS Online and Collector to conduct field surveys. I have a 'Web Map' (call this 'Web Map 1') that is 'served' to Collector which has a single point feature class in it. This point feature class collecting one item/feature that has a time date stamp to it. This all works fine.

In order to view the data I have also created a 'Web Mapping Application' to view the data via web browser. As the data I am collecting has time/date stamp I need to show records collected in the last 24 hours, 48 hours and all records. To do this I created 'View' layers of my original 'Hosted Layer' and applied a filter. I have added these 'View' layers to a new 'Web Map' (call this 'Web Map 2' as I want to keep my original 'Web Map' simple and just for collecting the data in Collector. The 'Web Mapping Application' use 'Web Map 2' for it's data. This works fine.

The issue I have is I only want staff to see 'Web Map 1' in Collector and not 'Web Map 2'

Is there anyway to only share (or setting) a 'Web Map' so that it is not visible in Collector but still visible to users as 'Web Mapping Application'?

Alternatively is there another way/workflow to do this?

Comment: Does the second web map with the view layers need to have editable layers? A map will only show up in Collector if its been flagged to be used in Collector when the map has editable layers.

Comment: Ideally yes, users would have the option to enter new records/edit existing data via the 'Web Mapping Application' which is tied to Web Map 2. So unfortunately this isn't really a way of controlling what is seen in Collector.

Comment: You can use ago-asistant and remove the Collector type keyword on the item. Similar to this - https://geonet.esri.com/thread/159682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended  up using [ago-asistant](https://ago-assistant.esri.com/) to view and edit the JSON of Web Map 2. In the JSON file I removed "Collector" from "typeKeywords" and it can no longer be seen in Collector.

```
    "typeKeywords": [
        "ArcGIS Online",
        "Data Editing",
        "Explorer Web Map",
        "Map",
        "Offline",
        "Online Map",
        "Web Map"
```

Using setting within AGOL Groups and sharing did not give me all the control I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You would want to share WebMap2 with a group that is not pushed to collector. This will allow the same layer to be viewed by both groups and either edited only by the collector group or by both. You get to define who is able to do what.

[Info on AGOL Groups Here](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/groups.htm)

> A group is a collection of maps and apps usually related to a specific
>   area of interest. You can create groups as a way to organize your
>   items. As a group owner, you decide who can find the group, if others
>   can request to join, and who can contribute content. You also have
>   control over items shared to the group and can invite others to join
>   who have the same type of account you have—organizational or public,
>   even if your group doesn't accept membership requests.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this really answers the question. If the users I want to share both Web Maps with are the same uses then I don't think that there is away of only sharing this just Collector or just a Web Mapping Application.

Comment: Then don't allow editing with the view only group/map